# Cannot upload large video to server

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using cakephp for my project. Here is my server's setting:

```
<?php
$config['PHP']['max_execution_time'] = '10000';     // session timeout (second) セッション有効期間 (秒単位) 
$config['PHP']['max_input_time'] = '10000';         

// File upload
$config['PHP']['post_max_size'] = '5000M';
$config['PHP']['memory_limit'] = '20000M';
$config['PHP']['upload_max_filesize'] = '5000M';
```

When I submit a form that uploads large size video (>100M), it lost all submitted parameters. But everything goes OK if I submit small size video.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Your HTTP server may also have a timeout you need to change. For apache2, it defaults to 300 seconds. You'd have to change that in the server configs.

Comment: Have you verified that all your settings is accepted from your server?

Answer (score 1):

Basically there is four options in php.ini that would preduce this.
To change this at runtime you could use the following:

**memory_limit**

```
ini_set( 'memory_limit', '256M' );
```

**max_execution_time**

```
ini_set( 'max_execution_time', 3600 ); or set_time_limit( 3600 );
```

**post_max_size**

```
Must be set in php.ini
```

Should be more than upload_max_filesize

**upload_max_filesize**

```
Must be set in php.ini as of the file would already be uploaded when the script is executed.
```

Looks like cakephp is using its own config system though.

You could validate this by running the following code in the end of your scripts:

```
var_dump( ini_get( 'memory_limit' ) );
var_dump( ini_get( 'max_execution_time' ) );
var_dump( ini_get( 'max_execution_time' ) );
var_dump( ini_get( 'post_max_size' ) );
```

Comment: after running following code:
var_dump( ini_get( 'post_max_size' ) );
I found out current 'post_max_size' is '80M' instead of '5000M' which I configured in setting.php file. Can you please tell me where '80M' was configured?

Answer (score 0):

You change value of **post_max_size** in file **php.ini**
example: **post_max_size = 500M**

Plz read more here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size